# Dampened mathematical pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system of ODEs
$$\begin{align*}\dot y &= v \\ \dot v &= -\lambda v - q(y) \end{align*}$$
for an increasing function $q$ such that $q(0)=0$ and the energy function $E= \frac 1 2 v^2 +Q(y)$ where $Q$ is an antiderivative of $q$. I want to show that the energy decreases with time.

I tried to differentiate E with respect to time, obtaining
\begin{align*}\dot E &= 2 \dot v v + Q'(y) \dot y \\
&=v(-2\lambda v -2 q(y) + q(y)) \\
&=-v(2\lambda v +q(y))\end{align*}
I don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $t$? ($y(t)$)

Comment: @JanEerland Yes, y depends on t (here, the dots are always derivatives wrt t). The system is just a reformulation of the following equation for the dampened pendulum: $\ddot y = - \lambda \dot y - q(y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $\quad \frac{1}{2}v^2\quad $ isn't $\quad 2 \dot v v\quad $ but $\quad \dot v v$ :

[image]
$$\dot E = -\lambda v^2 \quad\to\quad \dot E<0 \quad \text{ if } \lambda>0$$

Comment: Well that is an absolutely embarrassing mistake, thank you.